# css3 fade transition on links only works for some links on my website for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css

Here is a jsfiddle which works: http://jsfiddle.net/n52ES/

It is how I have it set up on my [website](http://keebs.com). However, if you notice on my website, only the 'subscribe' link in the footer (bottom center) works with the fade in transition on hover and the other links above it (i.e. google+, twitter) don't work. The same for the links at the very top right of the website in the navigation. I noticed this only happens in Chrome.

Does anyone have an idea as to why it only works for the 'subscribe' link? I'm lost.

Comment: I tried deactivating all Chrome extensions thinking it could be the problem but no dice...

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 16.0.912.77m

Comment: That is very strange. I am using the same version and the fade doesn't work on hover. It just changes colors. Glad to know it's working, though. I guess there is something wrong with my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Chrome stable has a bug that prevents it from animating visited links: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101245 (this is why you are able to see it, but other people won't unless they actually click and go back to your website).

I'd just wait for it to be fixed.